# Arquillian cube repeats each unit test multiple times

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, junit, jboss-arquillian

We are using Arquillian cube with JUnit to test containerised SpringBoot microservices.  This works fine, but for some reason the test harness is executing each individual test multiple times - 2, 3, sometimes 4 times each.  I can see no reason for this or find anything to explain it in the docs, and it's a nuisance rather than a major problem (at the moment).

Here is a cut down test class which I have used to demonstrate the issue:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class MyTests {

  @CubeIp(containerName = "test")
  private String cubeIp;

  @Test
  @InSequence(2)
  public void test1() {
    System.out.println("executing test1");
  }

  @Test
  @InSequence(2)
  public void test2() {
    System.out.println("executing test2");
  }
}
```

The console output with this example would show repeated debug for each test.  The `dockerContainers` configuration in `arquillian.xml` looks like this:

```
test:
    image: my-image:1.0
    await:
        strategy: sleeping
        sleepTime: 30 s
    portBindings: [1080->1080/tcp]
    restartPolicy:
        name: failure
        maximumRetryCount: 1
    links:
        - other-container:other-container

other-container:
    image: other-container:1.0
    portBindings: [8080->8080/tcp]
    restartPolicy:
        name: failure
        maximumRetryCount: 1
```

As can be seen, there is a second container `other-container` which mimics the behaviour of an upstream service. Both are started and stopped correctly.  I have tried upgrading all relevant Arquillian dependencies to the latest versions, but the problem persists.

Advice on why this is happening, whether it is expected behaviour (and why) or what we might be doing wrong in our config would be appreciated.

Comment: Exploring with Arquillian team via this issue: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube/issues/1105

Answer (score 0):

Removal of `<artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>` from our POM, which had been inadvertently included, solved this issue.